# How to find distinct (and greatest) values from collection using mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have following collection -

```
[{
    "customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db",
    "hostId" : "192.168.20.20",
    "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422007201815
}
{
    "customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db",
    "hostId" : "192.168.20.20",
    "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422008101736
}
{
    "customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db",
    "hostId" : "192.168.20.21",
    "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422009002239
}
{
    "customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db",
    "hostId" : "192.168.20.21",
    "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422009901379
}
{
    "customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db",
    "hostId" : "192.168.20.22",
    "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422010801685
}
{
    "customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db",
    "hostId" : "192.168.20.22",
    "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422010801585
}]
```

I also have list of hostIds as : [ "192.168.20.20" , "192.168.20.21" , "192.168.20.22"]

I want to match hostId list with collection and find latest (greatest) runtimeMilliSeconds only to get following output -

```
[{"hostId":"192.168.20.20", "runtime": 1422007201815},
{"hostId":"192.168.20.21", "runtime": 1422009002239},
{"hostId":"192.168.20.22", "runtime": 1422010801685}]
```

I have tried out following with mongo aggregation -

```
{ "$match" : { "hostId" : { "$in" : [ "192.168.20.20" , "192.168.20.21" , "192.168.20.22"]} ,
"customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db"}},
{ "$sort" : { "runtimeMilliSeconds" : -1}},
{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "hostId" : "$hostId" , 
"runtime" : "$runtimeMilliSeconds"}}},
{ "$project" : { "hostId" : "$_id.hostId" ,
 "runtimeMilliSeconds" : "$_id.runtime" , "_id" : 0}}
```

But it gives me all values in collection.

How do I get above mentioned output using mongo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I  think you are close to your answer but following some changes will meet your output

```
    {
    "$match": {
    "hostId": {
        "$in": [
            "192.168.20.20",
            "192.168.20.21",
            "192.168.20.22"
        ]
    },
    "customerId": "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db"
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "hostId": "$hostId",
        "runtime": "$runtimeMilliSeconds"
    }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
    "_id.runtime": -1
    }
}{
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.hostId",
    "runtime": {
        "$first": "$_id.runtime"
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**$first**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator

```
db.test.aggregate(
[
   { "$match" : { "hostId" : { "$in" : [ "192.168.20.20" , "192.168.20.21" , "192.168.20.22"]} , "customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db"}},
   { "$sort" : { "runtimeMilliSeconds" : -1}},
   { "$group" : { "_id" : { "hostId" : "$hostId" } , "runtime" : { $first : "$runtimeMilliSeconds" }}},   
   { "$project" : { "hostId" : "$_id.hostId" , "runtimeMilliSeconds" : "$runtime" , "_id" : 0}}
]
)
```

output will be:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "hostId" : "192.168.20.20",
            "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422008101736
        }, 
        {
            "hostId" : "192.168.20.21",
            "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422009901379
        }, 
        {
            "hostId" : "192.168.20.22",
            "runtimeMilliSeconds" : 1422010801685
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do that would be to use the [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator (no $sort stage needed):

```
[
    {"$match" : {
        "hostId" : { "$in" : [ "192.168.20.20" , "192.168.20.21" , "192.168.20.22"]},
        "customerId" : "54a32e9f1e14fa5476d654db"
    }},
    { "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$hostId",
        "runtime" : {"$max" : "$runtimeMilliSeconds"}
    }},
    {"$project" : {
        "hostId" : "$_id" ,
        "runtime" : 1,
        "_id" : 0
    }}
]
```